# How to apply button().trigger() outside DOM on angular datatables (l-lin) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

I have created a table like below with dtInstance:

```
   <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-column-defs="dtColumns" dt-instance="dtInstance" class="row-border hover">
   </table>
```

In controller I defined dtOptions and dtColumns:

```
 $scope.dtInstance = {};
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()

    .withDOM('frtip')
    .withButtons([
{
    extend: "excelHtml5",
    className: 'btn btn-success buttons-excel',
    filename: "List",
    title: "List",
    text: "Export",
    exportOptions: {
        columns: ':visible'
    },
    //CharSet: "utf8",
    exportData: { decodeEntities: true }

}
```

My question is I want to create a button outside the dt table and trigger the .withButtons export button when ng-click

I would also like to hide the .withButtons generated inside the table.

Got this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of undefined

when I use below code

```
<button ng-click="dtInstance.DataTable.button('.buttons-excel').trigger()">Download EXCEL</button>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with initializing dtInstance variable with `null` instead of `{}`:

```
$scope.dtInstance = null;
```

Keep everything else same.

Update:
Check if you've imported all the plugins required. Follow below example I've created to make sure:

**[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Psl4UGBsSaLtJrTjvvr2?p=preview)**

Comment: @Ron Have you imported all plugins required for this? Follow this official documentation: http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withButtons
Try adding this also: 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Ron Just cross check with the plunker example I've added. Check .withButtons method & the new Download Excel button I've added.